# MySQL get all rows where id = xxx and where the newest column in other table in row with same id is greater than one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two mysql-tables: `tbl_post` and `tbl_post_public`

`tbl_post` looks like this:

```
id | post_id   |  author  |  date (unix time)
--------------------------------
 0 |  xxxxx1   | User1   |  1489926071
 1 |  xxxxx2   | User2   |  1489926075
 2 |  xxxxx3   | User3   |  1489926079
```

this table includes all posts by users

now I have the `tbl_post_public` table:
this table contains the information, if the post of the user should be public.
if the user changes from public to private, the row doesn't get updated. it just adds a new row with the same post_id but with a newer timestamp
0 = public | 1 = private

```
    id | post_id | public | date (unix time)
    -----------------------------------------
 --> 0 |  xxxxx1 |  0     |  1489926071 <--| this two rows have the same
     1 |  xxxxx2 |  1     |                | post_id but the second is
     2 |  xxxxx3 |  0     |                | public = 1. I need to get 
 --> 3 |  xxxxx1 |  1     |  1489926099 <--| the second row because its newer
                    ^
                    |
```

so, in the result I want to have 10 Rows `(LIMIT 10)` ORDERED BY the date-column in tbl_post DESC WHERE author="User1" and WHERE the newest(date-column in tbl_post_public) row in tbl_post_public (which has the same post_id) and has public = 0

I hope you understand my question & sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the most recent row in the public table in various ways.  If you are filtering the posts, I would recommend a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             (select pp.public
              from tbl_post_public pp
              where pp.post_id = p.post_id
              order by date desc
              limit 1
             ) as latest_public
      from tbl_post p
      where . . .
     ) p
where public = 0
order by date desc
limit 10;
```

For performance purposes, you will want an index on `tbl_post_public(post_id, date)`.

If you don't have a `where` clause and you have an index on `tbl_post(date)`, then this is probably a bit faster:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             (select pp.public
              from tbl_post_public pp
              where pp.post_id = p.post_id
              order by date desc
              limit 1
             ) as latest_public
      from tbl_post p
      order by p.date desc
     ) p
where public = 0
limit 10;
```