# get only posts of users you follow mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

This question depends on my previous question:
[MySql get all rows where id = xxx and where the newest column in other table in row with same id is greater than one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42886619/mysql-get-all-rows-where-id-xxx-and-where-the-newest-column-in-other-table-in)

I'm currently using the following query to get all posts of all users that are public:

```
select p.*
    from (select p.*,
                 (select pp.public_type
                  from tbl_post_public pp
                  where pp.post_id = p.post_id
                  order by date desc
                  limit 1
                 ) as latest_public
          from tbl_post p
          order by p.date desc
         ) p
    where latest_public < 80
    limit 10;
```

but not i want to get only posts of users which im following like on instagram
i have following table to save who is following who:

tbl_user_follow:

```
id |  user     | follower_user | 
--------------------------------
 0 |  xxxxx4   | xxxxx1 (<-me) |
 1 |  xxxxx8   | xxxxx1 (<-me) |
 2 |  xxxxx3   | xxxxx6        |
```

so lets think that im the user "xxxxx1" and now i want the query to see all posts of "xxxxx4" and "xxxxx8" because im following them considering my previous question.

thank you very much and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Which DB are you using? You tagged both mysql and sql-server.

Comment: If your previous question was about MySQL then I assume this one is too.  Please don't put superfluous tags on your questions.

Comment: sorry... i'm using mysql

Comment: One problem I see is that you are giving multiple tables the same alias. That aside, you just need to do a join against the table (name?) with the follower_user.

Comment: okay i updated my question. the table name is "tbl_user_follow". I'm new to sql :) could you please answer if you know the query?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the name of the table in your question, or the field names in the other tables, so adjust the following to match those names. Also replace $user_id with the id to match.

```
select p1.*
    from (select p.*,
                (select pp.public_type
                from tbl_post_public pp
                where pp.post_id = p.post_id
                order by date desc
                limit 1
                ) as latest_public
        from tbl_post p
        order by p.date desc
        ) p1
    JOIN `tbl_user_follow` f
    ON f.`user` = p1.`user`
    where latest_public < 80
    AND (f.`follower_user` = $userID OR f.`user` = $userID)
    GROUP BY f.`follower_user`, f.`user`
    limit 10;
```

Comment: thank you very much! it works! could you please tell me how i can also get own posts? so something like "AND f.`follower_user` = $userID OR p1.'user' = $userID"

Comment: Just _select * from tbl_post where  `user` = $user_ID;_ Also, if it worked for you please accept the answer.

Comment: hehe yes i will accept the answer. but could you please write the complete query with 'select * from tbl_post where user = $user_ID' ? im a noob in mysql :)

Comment: i already tried it with 'OR p1.`user` = '$userID'' after 'AND f.`follower_user` = '$userID'. but this gives out one row six times

Comment: That was the complete query for just your posts. Are you wanting to add your own posts to the other query? Not sure why you would want that in the same query.

Comment: Yes i want the existing query also with my own posts

Comment: it works but now im getting each of my own posts six times

Comment: @Musk, You can probably solve that by using a group by.

Comment: hehe thanks but i dont know how i could do that :) sorry :) could you please update your query? thank you very much!

Comment: @Mush: I've updated the answer, but without knowing what you get for results, it's difficult to know which fields should be used in the group by. Run the query without the group by, and look at the columns to determine which ones should be used.